# how to enter bold-backslash in latex?

Tags: beamer, symbols

I am using beamer making a presentation, I want to add a bold backslash inside a text, `\textbf{\textbackslash}` does not seem to work, can someone tell me please how to enter a bold-backslash? 
the code is something like this:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer} 
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usecolortheme{beaver} 


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Differences in File-systems}
\begin{itemize}
\item (backslash) {\color{red}{\textbf{\textbackslash}}} in windows:\\ \vspace{5 mm}
\textbf{c:\textbackslash Documents and Settings\textbackslash Maria\textbackslash My Documents\textbackslash lec-1.doc}\vspace{5mm}
\item (forward slash) \textbf{{\color{red}{/}}} in linux: \\ \vspace{5 mm}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \textbf{\textbackslash} \textbackslash
\end{document}` works for me → http://i.stack.imgur.com/dTkl2.png

Comment: thanks, @Harish. what you have suggested will enter two backslashes like this (\\), the \textbf{} is not working for \textbackslash

Comment: The second one is for comparison, The first one is bold compared to second in my picture.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Kind of you  @Martin, I edited the question to make it more clear, Thanks.

Comment: `\usepackage{fontspec}` and switch to `lualatex`/`xelatex`. It's 2015.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your question is very unclear but I assume from the tag you are using beamer.

```
\documentclass{beamer}


%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\showoutput
 \begin{document}
\begin{frame}
   \textbf{aaa\textbackslash}

  aaa \textbackslash 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Produces the warning

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/cmss/bx/n' undefined
(Font)              using `OMS/cmsy/m/n' instead
(Font)              for symbol `textbackslash' on input line 11.
```

Telling you that `\` comes from the math sans serif and there is no bold in OT1 encoding.

Adding

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

The warning goes away and you get:

[image]

where if you look closely (or at the output from `\showoutput`) the `\` is bold.

Comment: Thanks @David, Yes I am using beamer. I used the \textbf{} as I noticed in the question, the problem was I have not added the package {fontenc}. I will edit the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @Mahtab every question should have a complete document, like the one here so people can test. Note the version in the Harish's comment does work as that uses roman font and there is bold. The problem is that beamer uses sans serif which has a smaller range of available fonts. So it is _all_ about beamer not about latex in general and certainly not about tex-core as it was originally tagged.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think _every question_ might be a bit strong, perhaps more _it is usually a good idea if possible_

Comment: @JosephWright I used to use a form of words like that but I think it's simpler just to say every. Every rule has an exception, so it comes to the same thing.

Comment: While I can understand why _you_ promote T1, it's 2015, so IMHO people should use luatex/xetex and `fontspec`.

Comment: @MartinSchröder at some point they may be the first choice stable formats and the current svn latex sources have a lot of work to make the format work out of the box with those engines, and run the test suite on all three, but currently they are really for people who definitely need those features, and (less of an issue for beamer, presumably) most publication submission requirements will not accept documents that don't work with pdftex, so I would not currently recommend the unicode engines for a question not specifically needing that.